# creating menu for android game

Tags: android

I'd like to create menu for my game like in pictures where MI1 is any item with an image,
it is clicable and after click there will apear menu like at an image1 where I1-I5 are clickable items with images. I'm new with android games can you say me any ideas about how to do it?

[image]
I1-I7 items of menu
MI1 item for call menu

[image]

MI1 until click

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are familiar with basics of Android development and already know what a layout, visibility, or a click listener is.

I would suggest using [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) to arrange the elements on the screen. It allows you to position items on the screen in relation to each other. So for example you could have MI1 located in absolute center of the screen, then you could position I1 above MI1, I2 to the right of MI1 and so forth. The full list of available layout parameters is available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). You will want to set the visibility of I1, I2, ... to "gone" originally, so they wouldn't be visible.

Then, you would add an OnClickListener to MI1, which would switch the visibility of I1, I2, ... to "visible" when MI1 is clicked.